# Default open nav bar when html page first loads

Tags: html, css

How do I modify this code to keep my side nav bar open when the page first loads in? I want my side nav open by default.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div></div>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Learn Here</span>

    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <img src="https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg" height="20%" width="70%" style="padding-left: 36px; padding-right: 36px">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a class="nav_padding" href="#">About me</a>
      <a class="nav_padding" href="#">Resume</a>
      <a class="nav_padding" href="#">Projects</a>
      <a class="nav_padding" href="#">Contact Me</a>
      <script>
      </script>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: You've got the code for `onclick` already. Think about how you could use that on page load. Hint: there is built-in JS code to listen for page load.

Comment: i am fairly new to JS so I have no clue.

Comment: see just add the script i gave below in answer it also have an explanation there

Comment: Where is your element with `id="main"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add script on $(document).ready(function(){ });
ready function executes java script on page load ,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
});
</script>
```

Comment: Bringing in jQuery solely for waiting for the HTML to load is grossly overkill, especially when the OP doesn't include jQuery anywhere.

Comment: Do I need to delete the other scripts?

Comment: no you need to add this to your code, don't remove any of previous code. Also include link to jquery library ,

Comment: Thanks Adern Nerk! Got it!

Comment: if you think this answer solves your problem , then mark this answer as answered. So that others could see that this question has been asnwered

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `CSS`.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '250px';
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)';
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '0px';
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Learn Here</span>

    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <img src="https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg" height="20%" width="70%" style="padding-left: 36px; padding-right: 36px">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a class="nav_padding" href="#">About me</a>
      <a class="nav_padding" href="#">Resume</a>
      <a class="nav_padding" href="#">Projects</a>
      <a class="nav_padding" href="#">Contact Me</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the width that gets added via JS to be added inline to start with. It gets overriden when the menu close button is clicked.

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" style="width: 250px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I  rearranged your code a bit and was able to get it to work using the onload Event Attribute:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
             <script>
                 function openNav() {
                     document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
                     document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
                     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
                 }

                 function closeNav() {
                     document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
                     document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
                     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                 }
                 </script>
         </header>

         <body onload="openNav()">
             <nav>
                 <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Learn Here</span>
                 <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                     <img src="images/tab.png" height="20%" width="70%" style="padding-left: 36px; padding-right: 36px">
                     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                     <a class="nav_padding" href="#">About me</a>
                     <a class="nav_padding" href="#">Resume</a>
                     <a class="nav_padding" href="#">Projects</a>
                     <a class="nav_padding" href="#">Contact Me</a>
                 </div>
             </nav>
         </body>
     </div>
```